# Page not found while run production build react js on reload

Tags: reactjs, deployment, react-router

I have created a production build for my react app with **npm run build** or **yarn run  build**. And i deployed that production build on server and it's running fine.

But when someone reload the page, then it shows

> page not found.

I searched this issue on stackoverflow and someone suggested  to create .htaccess file at root of the server. But **i already have the .htaccess file** on my server and my production build is running inside the **sub-folder**.

**Note:** I have deployed my app inside sub-folder of root directory and accessing the app with www.abc.com/react

Can anyone please help with this issue? Thanks is advance.

Comment: sounds like your server isn't configured properly to route non `/` paths to `/`. What are you using to host?

Comment: Could be an issue with your react-router setup as well, but hard to say without more context.

Comment: I have deploye react build to cpanel

Comment: I deployed in a sub-directory

Comment: You need to make sure that your server is serving the `index.html` file for every `react-router` route you have.

Comment: This is not a htaccess issue. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually

Comment: @Tholle, So please let me know. How can i test that case?

Comment: Remember that Create react app makes a single page app, so if you try to refresh whatever page besides index page it will return page not found, to do that instead you will have to do a SSR (Server Side Render) react application or also called isomorphic. There's a library called Next.js for react ssr apps. You can find more info on Next.org.

Comment: @vitomadio, You mean to say i can't achieve what i want to with static react apps?

Comment: exactly, you can navigate through pages with react router but you can't refresh any page, because the server is only render index page "/", in order to be able to refresh every single page you need the server to serve or render every path /home, /about, and so on. That's why you need to make your react app ssr.

Comment: @vitomadio, Do i need to use any backend framework or language for that?

Comment: If you go for Next it's everything under the hood maybe a little of node.js knowledge would be great, but that will depend on your needs.

Comment: you don't need next.js for this.  you might have to change your home route from '/' to /*' on your server.